# How do I know what drivers I'm missing?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I've installed Windows XP recently and I want to install all the drivers like the wireless and graphics card drivers

Answer (score 2):

If you open device manager you will see all devices receiving errors with their drivers

Example:
[image]

To access Device Manager, use any of the following methods:
Click Start, click Run, and then type `devmgmt.msc`
Right-click My Computer, click Manage, and then click Device Manager.
Right-click My Computer, click Properties, click the Hardware tab, and then click Device Manager.
Type the following command at a command prompt: `start devmgmt.msc`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer, right click each item you are missing drivers for and select properties. Then click on the details tab and choose "Hardware Ids". Take note of the ven/dev no and go to a site like pcdatabase.com to give you an idea of what manufacturer/device you need to get the driver for. If the driver is not available from the manufacturers website then try driverpacks.net.